# How to protect a script execution on Wordpress?

Tags: wpdb, security, cron

Recently I have created a script to update records on my Wordpress database. I basically use **wpdb** to connect to another database, grap some records, and update the Wordpress database. Using only Wordpress, the initial solution that I found was put all the code on a custom template. So, when I visit a given URL, the update occurs.

This custom template do all the operations by itself, I don't even pass any argument to it. I only need to run/visit an URL.

The thing is that I don't want this script to be accessible to anyone, but at the same time, I need to run it on a scheduled cron job. So, what would be the better way to protect this script? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

One approach (*avoiding PHP timeouts*) for a local Linux Cron Job (*for exact timing*) is creating a WP-CLI [command](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/guides/commands-cookbook/#required-registration-arguments) (*does not run in the browser*), like:

```
<?php /* Plugin Name: WP-CLI Foo */

function foo_command( $args ) {
    // Adjust to your needs ...
    WP_CLI::success( $args[0] );
}

WP_CLI::add_command( 'foo', 'foo_command' );
```

and the corresponding command line might be like:

```
wp --path=/full/path/to/wp-config.php foo bar
```

where `foo` is the command and `bar` is the argument.

One can also use WordPress' own [Cron API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) and there are [ways](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=cron%20external) to sync it with an external cron job via url, if precice run times are needed.

There's also the [cron command](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/cron/) of WP-CLI.

Comment: Nice approach. Never used WP-CLI before, I will give it a try. Thanks!